# What is the property reference for checking for .NET Framework 4.5 in WiX?

Tags: wix, .net-framework-version

I am using WiX Toolset 3.7, and I need to check for the installation of .NET Framework 4.5 in my installer.  However, the [Documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm) does not seem to be updated to include 4.5 properties.  There is a bug that seems to imply that such properties do exist: https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/3167/, but I could not find a reference.  I tried just copying the 4.0 property and using NETFRAMEWORK45FULL but the WiX compiler failed to recognize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking through the WiX source code, I found the properties.  The one I decided to use was simply NETFRAMEWORK45.  The others can be found here: 
http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62deafa7b2a4#src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx4.5.wxs

UPDATE: Moved to https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/blob/709560017c322dca0059d1c8849184e22b85bea7/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx4.5.wxs

Comment: Dead link. Since WiX moved to Github the new link is https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/blob/709560017c322dca0059d1c8849184e22b85bea7/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx4.5.wxs